# IdentityServer4 forced logout

Tags: identityserver4

How to trigger a (complete) logout for a user *externally*, from a *different user's* session?

For example - an "Admin" logs in and signs out user "JohnDoe" (from IdentityServer and all the clients).

IdentityServer supports notifying clients (via the front or back channels) when a user logs out. That's great, but how to start the ball rolling from outside the user's session?

Comment: Can you explain why you want this functionality? What would be a reason for an admin to do so?

Comment: For the same reasons you'd want to revoke a reference or refresh tokens.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with tokens is that you can't delete the token, you'll have to revoke it  by removing it from the store so it can't be used anymore. In fact, with back channel logout you have the same problem. You can't directly delete the cookie, but the client can reject it on the next request.

With a user session, back channel logout can read the session information from the cookie available at the IdentityServer website. The admin however, has no access to this information so you'll need to store the user sessions server side.

This can be either at the client or at the IdentityServer. I would implement a session manager at the client, because it's the client that validates the cookie and can delete the cookie (on the next request).

This allows IdentityServer to perform a normal back channel logout and leave it to the client to remove one or all entries from the session manager on `LogoutCallback`. This way you can implement different strategies for different clients.

The client can consult the session manager on cookie validation and deny access if the session is not available. Something like:

```
public class CookieEventHandler : CookieAuthenticationEvents
{
    private SessionManager _sessionManager { get; }

    public CookieEventHandler(SessionManager sessionManager)
    {
        _sessionManager = sessionManager;
    }

    public override async Task ValidatePrincipal(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
    {
        if (context.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var sub = context.Principal.FindFirst("sub")?.Value;

            if (!_sessionManager.HasSession(sub))
            {
                context.RejectPrincipal();
                await context.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In startup:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
    {
        options.EventsType = typeof(CookieEventHandler);
    })
```

Comment: Thank you.
Your answer however seem to be more about "how a client should implement a back channel logout", rather than "how an admin user can force a logout for someone else". Except for the "The admin however, has no access to this information so you'll need to store the user sessions server side." part.

Comment: Because the flow can be quite the same, the only difference is the source of the user session information. So you'll need to create a similar method that can be called by the admin. When the admin wants to perform a general logout for another user then resolve the sub of that user and notify the clients (new back channel method). As described, when you let the client keep track of the sessions then you can easily remove the sessions from the session manager (using sub) and on the next request remove the cookies as well. It's up to you how and where the admin can select users.

Comment: Does that answer your question or can you otherwise explain what you are missing in my answer?

Comment: Clients can be on different browsers and even different machines. It seems to me that the source of truth can only be the server. The client's responsibility is to provide a back channel for logging out users. That's it. How the client will go about it is irrelevant as far as the server is concerned.

So if user's sessions are stored server-side, then in theory I can see how an admin could enumerate them, generate logout tokens and call the registered back channel URLs.

Comment: To make sure we are talking about the same thing, with client I mean the client app like an mvc client (server side). You can keep track of sessions at IdentityServer, but like you said, IdentityServer only has to signal a user is logged out and then leave it to the client to act accordingly. The question is where to select the user to logout. But in fact that doesn't matter if you have an endpoint that the admin can use to trigger a back channel logout for a user.